# Can I use Jetpack compose icons outside @Composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-jetpack-compose, drawable

Can I use Jetpack compose icons outside @Composable?

I would like to convert compose icons (actually instances of `ImageVector`) to `Bitmap` or `Drawable`. How to achieve this?

All methods like `rememberVectorPainter()` or `Image()` requiring @Composable context. But I just want to use them as ordinary `Bitmap/Drawable`, is it possible?

Comment: If you looked into how each icon is made (i.e looking at the source code of any icon) perhaps you will get it ... I think it's not possible ...

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to convert compose icons (actually instances of ImageVector)

`ImageVector` is a class in `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector`, which means it can only be used if you use the Compose libraries.

Good news is all the material icons can be obtained as SVG or PNG which can be used as Drawable resources with Android Studio's [Resource Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager) (Tools Menu -> Resource Manager). Also check out related [vector asset studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)

You can get the icons (SVG and PNG versions) [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons).

Just click on the icon and a pane will pop up on the right with blue buttons to download the icons.

Comment: Nope, I would like to have them like in [Android Iconics library](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics), I know, that I can download them as SVG/PNG but it's not what I want.

Comment: [Android Iconics](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) does not serve your purpose either? Google Material Design Icons are in the [list of Already available fonts](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics#whats-included-)
If you would like to import [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) objects like `Icons.Filled` and pass its member variables to some function/class that will display them outside of a `@Composable` without using Android Iconics, I am afraid you may have to create your own function/class that understands the `ImageVector` class.

Comment: No, I mean I was using Android Iconics for deploying from GMD fonts necessary icons just referencing them like: `MaterialDesignIconic.Icon.gmi_camera`. I thought would it be possible to do the same with composable fonts, but out of compose context :)

Comment: specifically, how to convert ImageVector to drawable ?
I use `androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.4` ,
But I hope use it as drawable in other third-party libraries, so I don't need to maintain two resources

Comment: @lisonge I would like to use `ImageVector` in legacy Android code (notifications, widgets etc) so have a similar requirement. Any progress?